# Add filter to PartialDate

Tags: django

I have date collected like PartialDate
if date is complete, date is in english format ('yyyy-mm-dd') in my template
I would like to convert this date into french format but considering the date can be partial

if only year is known, I would like to see 2019
if only year and month areknown, I would like to see 10/2019 (convert 2019-10 to 10/2019)
and if the date is complete, I would like to see 16/10/2019 (convert 2019-10-16 to 16/10/2019)

I tried to add some logic in my template

```
{% if participante.pat_nai_dat|length_is:"4" %}
    //do something
{% elif participante.pat_nai_dat|length_is:"7" %}
    //do something
{% else %}
    {{ participante.pat_nai_dat|date:"d/m/Y" }}
{% endif %}
```

but length_is and date filtesr do not work with PartialDate object
I've read Django documentation to for more appropriate filter but did not find any
my approach is probably wrong...
how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem using personalized filter

Answer (score 0):

PartialDate has methods that return True/False depending on the precision.

```py
>>> partial_date = PartialDate("2015-11-01")
>>> partial_date.precisionDay()
True
>>> partial_date.precisionMonth()
False
>>> partial_date.precisionYear()
False
```

Should you want it printed in a format, PartialDate supports that too!

```py
>>> partial_date.format('%Y', '%m/%Y', '%m/%d/%Y')
'11/01/2015'
>>> partial_date = PartialDate("2015-11")
>>> partial_date
2015-11
>>> partial_date.format('%Y', '%m/%Y', '%m/%d/%Y')
'11/2015'
```

and as such I believe , format would be exactly what you need

I suggest having a look at [PyPi's documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-partial-date/)